# Javascript: Find earliest time

Tags: javascript

```
var slots = [
  [['11:30', '13:30']], // eg. Mr.X is free for a meeting during this time
  [['12:00', '14:00'], ['16:30', '17:30']], // eg. Mr.Y is free for a meeting during this time
  [['12:15', '15:00'], ['16:30', '17:45']]  // eg. Mr.Z is for for a meeting during this time
];
```

`slots` are 3D array that contains available time ranges for any meeting schedule.

***I need to find the earliest time, when every person is free.***.

eg. here, `12:15` is desired earliest time, cause its between `['11:30', '13:30'] and ['12:00', '14:00']`.

Here `slots` are in order by person, but might not always. ie.

```
var slots = [   
   [['12:00', '14:00'], ['16:30', '17:30']], // eg. Mr.Y is free for a meeting during this time   
   [['11:30', '13:30']], // eg. Mr.X is free for a meeting during this time               
   [['12:15', '15:00'], ['16:30', '17:45']]  // eg. Mr.Z is for for a meeting during this time 
];
```

may also happen. Also any number of slots possible for a person, so earliest may not always from first slot, could be from any slot.

I tried some way but nothing worked.

Comment: What have you tried? Can time ranges overlap? Will the times ranges of each person be sorted?

Comment: @Oriol Sir, actually I'm confused how to start at all, what ever I tried nothing in way and time ranges will not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see...

- I would create an array that contains all the possible 15-minute time slots in chronological order.
- Initially fill all the time slot array elements with 0.
- Go through every persons appointment array (in no particular order) and add 1 to each time slot that's being used by anyone.
- When you've finished, any time slot element with a zero value is available by everyone.
- The time slot with a zero value and an index closest to zero is the first available time.

Comment: why 15-minutes slots?

Comment: The appointments you show us are aligned on 15 minute boundaries. 11:30 == 11 + 2*15, 13:30 == 13 + 2*15, 12:00 == 12 + 0*15 ... and so on  ;-)

Comment: But Sir, there is not such boundary limit.

Comment: Chuckle...OK, then your timeslots array would contain an element for every available time slice (whether that slice consists of 15 minutes or 1 minute or 1 millisecond).

Comment: @markE has a valid point. Without a boundary you can get edge cases like. Mr. X is free on 12:21, so is Mr. Y, but Mr. X is going into meeting at 12:22. So he's free for just one minute.